# Windows 10: clone drive with relocated userprofile

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, clone, sysprep

I've been asked to clone an existing HDD (for replacement) on a Windows 10 (1909) PC. My concern isn't the cloning process specifically; this PC has had sysprep/OOBE run to move all %USERPROFILE% to D: -- which is the drive to be cloned/replaced.

The plan is to clone the drive via a liveCD or second system and replace it before booting; my question is whether the moved user profiles directory complicates matters. Are there any additional steps that need to be performed to ensure Windows treats the new D: drive identically to the old, or is the relocated Users directory unaffected by this operation?

The two drives are nominally the same capacity (I can pre-shrink the source filesystem if necessary) but have different manufacturers. C: and D: are the only drives on the system, C: will remain as-is.

Comment: Is the cloned drive going to replace the old drive?

Comment: @LPChip Yes. If it's brought back in subsequently (as E: or similar) it would be formatted first.

Comment: If its not going to have the old drive letter back or formatted, you will obviously have problems with the profile.

Comment: At this point the goal is just to replace D: and leave it at that.

Comment: Then it should be no problem.

Comment: @LPChip This worked as you said once the clone had its drive letter corrected via DISKPART (Macrium set it to E: at first); thanks. Rather than answering my own question I'll accept yours if posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cloned drive is going to replace your old drive, then there's no problem.

Make sure the drive to be cloned has not changed, and then clone the drive. After the cloning, replace the drives, boot into windows setup, hit shift-f10 at the first screen to access command prompt, and use diskpart to change the driveletter to D: and all should be fine.